# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{i^n}{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to show that this series converges $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{i^n}{n}.$$ It is easy to see that it is not absolutely convergent. No use looking at the radius of convergence either.  Can Someone help me?

Comment: @JohnColtraneisJC: I guess that $i$ is the imaginary number.

Comment: Consider the real and imaginary terms separately.

Comment: the partial sums $\sum_{n \le N} i^n$ are bounded and $1/n \to 0$

Comment: You guys are right, my mistake.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2442016/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2004192/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/653766/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bi%5En%7D%7Bn%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: Whoever voted to reopen the question: It would be helpful to leave a *comment* explaining why you think that the question is not a duplicate. As far as I can see, the exact question has been asked and answered before (and all solutions presented here are also presented in the older threads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It converges by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test): the partial sumes of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty i^n$ are bounded, the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is monotonic and converges to $0$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{i^n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n}+i\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}.$$

Comment: @Lucas: How will you decompose $i$ in real and imaginary part ? :-) Just remark that $i^{4n}=1$, $i^{4n+1}=i$, $i^{4n+2}=-1$ and $i^{4n+3}=-i$. The claim will follow.

Comment: got it, but isn't this a rearrangement?

Comment: you accepted an answer ! Even if I don't understand why, go for it ;-) @Lucas

Comment: I marked José's answer as right, I understood all the steps, but his solution seems more elementary to me and I believe it enriches my arsenal of techniques to understand all the solutions. I gave an upvote because I think it is important to value people's goodwill, I also value a healthy discussion even without rewards. :-)

Comment: yes sure :-) It's a very good point he gave you a good answer :-) But still... I'm really not able to understand his answer... I'm probably very stupid !@Lucas

Comment: Dirichlet's test, I noticed that $\frac{1}{(n + 1)}<\frac{1} {n}$ is all $n$ and $lim \frac{1}{n} = 0$

I was convinced that $| \sum_ {i = 1}^N i^n |<3$ for all $N$. this is the most delicate point, right? the rest of the problem has been shifted to Dirichlet's test. Is something wrong with what I'm thinking based on the other answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97641/discussion-between-lucas-and-surb).